# What does it mean to have an 'empty' case statement in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax

How does the compiler interpret this?:

```
foo match {
  case bar: Bar => println("First case statement")
  case _ => 
}
```

The second case is left empty, with nothing to return.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It means return `Unit`:

```
val res: Unit = new foo match {
  case bar: Bar => println("First case statement")
  case _ =>
}
```

If you change your statement to return something instead of `println` (which returns `Unit`):

```
val res: Any = new foo match {
  case bar: Bar => "it's a bar"
  case _ =>
}
```

Now the compiler has inferred `Any` because it's the first common supertype between `String` and `Unit`.

Note that your case match is wrong because matching on `bar` alone means catch all the variables, you probably wanted `bar: Bar`.

Answer (score 6):

The *empty **default*** case is necessary in your pattern matching example, because otherwise the
match expression would throw a MatchError for every expr argument that is not a bar.

The fact that no code is specified for that second case, so if that case runs it does nothing.

The result of either case is the Unit value **()**, which is also, therefore, the result of the entire match expression.

More details on it in Martin Odersky's **Programming in Scala** book under **Case Classes and Pattern Matching** chapter.